# MongoDB: Log a random record from collection to the console

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb atlas and node.js. I am trying to retrieve a random record from my collection "personal_information". it seems as though I should used use :

```
  db.collection("personal_information").aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]);
```

but I am unsure as to how to log the result onto the console.
Any ideas?

UPDATE
this is what the entire section looks like

```
 const findCustomer = function(db, callback) {

   db.collection("personal_information").aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } 
   }], function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) })
}
```

however the this is a snippet of what is logged to the console:

```
 AggregationCursor {
_readableState: ReadableState {
  objectMode: true,
  highWaterMark: 16,
  buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
  length: 0,
  pipes: [],
  flowing: null,
  ended: false,
  endEmitted: false,
  reading: false,
  sync: true,
  needReadable: false,
  emittedReadable: false,
  readableListening: false,
  resumeScheduled: false,
  errorEmitted: false,
  emitClose: true,
  autoDestroy: true,
  destroyed: false,
  errored: null,
  closed: false,
  closeEmitted: false,
  defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
  awaitDrainWriters: null,
  multiAwaitDrain: false,
  readingMore: false,
  decoder: null,
  encoding: null,
  [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
},
```

Comment: Use async/await and store in variable

`var result = await db.collection("personal_information").aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]);
`
`console.log(result)`

Comment: `db.collection("personal_information").aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }], function( err, data ) { console.log(err, data) } )` can use

Comment: please see the edits i made to the post